# TAB key indents entire row instead of only text right of cursor

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu, shortcut-keys, kde, kate

The TAB key is giving me unexpected behaviour in the text editor Kate on Kubuntu 14.04.3 LTS:

**Action**

Press TAB key.

**Expected behaviour**

Everything to the right of the cursor indents.

**Actual behaviour**

The entire row (also everything left from the cursor) indents.

**System info**

- Distro: Kubuntu 14.04.3
- Qt: 4.8.6
- KDE Development Platform: 4.13.3
- Kate: 3.13.3
- Kernel: 3.19.0-43-generic

I have already triple-checked Kate's configuration but I was unable find anything related to this. Maybe I am overlooking something. Does anyone know how to change this behaviour?

Answer (score -1):

In Settings -> Configure Kate -> Editing (on the left) -> Indentation (tab) -> Indentation Actions (on the bottom), select "Increase indentation level if in leading blank space".